# Prestashop 1.7 images not showing after add

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, e-commerce

Im importing products with images:

```
if (count($d->images)) {
    foreach ($d->images as $img) {
        $url = $img->url;
        $cover = boolval($img->cover);
        $position = intval($img->position);

        $image = new Image();
        $image->id_product = $pid;
        $image->position = $position;
        $image->legend = $img->legend;
        $image->cover = $cover;

        if (($image->validateFields(false, true)) === true &&
            ($image->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true && $image->add())
        {
            $image->associateTo(1);
            if (!AdminImportController::copyImg($pid, $image->id, $url, 'products', true))
            {
                $image->delete();
            }
        }

    }
} else {
    file_put_contents('no_images.txt',$d->name." \n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

but images not showing on page. On admin backend images existst and showing but on page frontend they not display. I have to open manually edit product and click Save to "refresh" images and make it possible to load display on page. How to do it in php code? Is there any way to refresh all images in prostashop products or refresh in php code images for product id?

Comment: Before click Save check if exists record on ps_image_shop

Comment: Yes in this case I have two records exists cover and image so it looks like in database is all right.. but Prestashop generating real thumbnails only after manual click Save.. its big problem because I have 10,000+ products to add.. I tried to regenerate ALL thumbnails in Images settings but not working too.

Comment: Thumbnails exists in directory so there is some problem with indexing them, Prestashop problem...

Comment: I suggest to study what AdminProductController does when Save button is submitted

Comment: POSTs ps-admin/index.php/sell/catalog/products/33744?_token= action but I can't locate in controller this code